# Fazer sort num array de strings com datas

Tags: javascript, array, classificação

Tenho o seguinte array:

`let datas = ["nov/2018", "set/2018", "jan/2019", "dez/2018", "out/2018"]`

quando executo

`datas.sort()`

ele ordena por ordem alfabética, porém, preciso ordenar primeiro pelo ano e depois pela ordem alfabética.

`["dez/2018", "jan/2019", "nov/2018", "out/2018", "set/2018"]`

Testando hoje cheguei na seguinte linha de código:

```js
var datas = ["mar", "abr", "jan", "dez", "set", "mai", "jun", "out", "jul"];
var datas_corretas = ["jan", "fev", "mar", "abr", "mai", "jun", "jul", "ago", "set", "out", "nov", "dez"];
var result = [];

datas_corretas.forEach(function ordenar(element, index){
  var mes = datas.filter(function(valor){
  return valor == datas_corretas[index];
});
  result.push(mes[0]);
  for(element of result){
    if (element === undefined || element === null){
      result.pop(element);
    }
  }
});
console.log(result);
```

Dessa forma eu consigo ordenar os dados, porém o problema é quando uso com o ano

`var datas = ["mar/2018", "abr/2018", "jan/2019", "dez/2018", "set/2018", "mai/2018", "jun/2018", "out/2018", "jul/2018"];`

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se quer ordenar pelo ano e depois pelo mês alfabeticamente e mantendo o array no formato que tem pode fazer assim:

```js
let datas = ["nov/2018", "set/2018", "jan/2019", "dez/2018", "out/2018"];

datas.sort((data1, data2) => {
  const [mes1, ano1] = data1.split('/');
  const [mes2, ano2] = data2.split('/');
  
  return ano1 !== ano2 ? Number(ano2) - Number(ano1) : mes1.localeCompare(mes2);
});

console.log(datas.join("\n"));
```

Antes de cada comparação entre datas ele pega no texto e divide em duas partes pela `/`, obtendo assim o nome do mês e o ano. Depois se os anos forem diferentes ordena pelo ano caso contrário ordena pelo mês através do [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare).

Embora o código funcione, este formato de datas não é o ideal e acaba por fazer bastante mais trabalho que o normal por dividir os mesmos textos várias vezes.

**Edit:**

Se a ordenação por mês não é para ser alfabetica e sim por ordem dos meses, quer isto dizer, Janeiro  equivale a 1, Fevereiro a 2, e por ai em diante pode fazer assim:

```js
const meses = ["jan", "fev", "mar", "abr", "mai", "jun", "ago", "set", "out", "nov", "dez"];
let datas = ["nov/2018", "set/2018", "jan/2019", "dez/2018", "out/2018"];

datas.sort((data1, data2) => {
  const [mes1, ano1] = data1.split('/');
  const [mes2, ano2] = data2.split('/');
  
  return ano1 !== ano2 ? Number(ano2) - Number(ano1) : meses.indexOf(mes1) - meses.indexOf(mes2);
});

console.log(datas.join("\n"));
```

Agora já foi preciso um array de meses para se saber qual a ordem correta dos meses.

Se a ordenação é crescente ou decrescente depende da ordem com que coloca as variáveis nas comparações. Quando faz `Number(ano2) - Number(ano1)` tem ano decrescente mas se fizer `Number(ano1) - Number(ano2)` já dá crescente. O mesmo principio se aplica aos meses, e por isso invertendo para `meses.indexOf(mes2) - meses.indexOf(mes1)` faz a ordenação decrescente de meses.

Comment: Também acho que não seja a melhor forma de se armazenar datas, e também fui ver que só dessa não fica um código reaproveitável, pois testei colocar o mês de `abr/2018`, e ele ficou na frente de `jan/2018`

Comment: @RaphaelMeloDeLima Não é alfabeticamente os meses ? Alfabeticamente é como esta na minha resposta. É por ordem de mês = Janeiro equivale a 1 e por ai fora ? Se é isso então não se expressou corretamente na pergunta, nem leu atentamente a minha resposta. Mas caso seja é só dizer que eu edito a resposta

Comment: @RaphaelMeloDeLima De qualquer forma já editei a resposta, e por isso neste momento tem ambas as versões.

Comment: Realmente me expressei de uma forma errada, peço desculpas por isso e muito obrigado pela atenção

Answer (score 0):

Ajustando sua array para:

```
<script>
var array = [{id: 1, date: Mar 12 2012 10:00:00 AM}, {id: 2, date: Mar 8 2012 08:00:00 AM}];
</script>
```

Você pode obter uma resposta simples como:

```
<script>
array.sort(function(a,b){
  // Transforme suas strings em datas e subtraia-as
  // para obter um valor que seja negativo, positivo ou zero.
  return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date);
});
</script>
```

Resposta Genérica e Poderosa
Defina uma função sortBy não enumerável personalizada usando uma transformação [Schwartzian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) em todos os arrays:

```
<script>
(function(){
  if (typeof Object.defineProperty === 'function'){
    try{Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype,'sortBy',{value:sb}); }catch(e){}
  }
  if (!Array.prototype.sortBy) Array.prototype.sortBy = sb;

  function sb(f){
    for (var i=this.length;i;){
      var o = this[--i];
      this[i] = [].concat(f.call(o,o,i),o);
    }
    this.sort(function(a,b){
      for (var i=0,len=a.length;i<len;++i){
        if (a[i]!=b[i]) return a[i]<b[i]?-1:1;
      }
      return 0;
    });
    for (var i=this.length;i;){
      this[--i]=this[i][this[i].length-1];
    }
    return this;
  }
})();
</script>
```

Use assim:

```
<script>
array.sortBy(function(o){ return o.date });
</script>
```

Se a sua data não for diretamente comparável, faça uma data comparável, por exemplo:

```
<script>
array.sortBy(function(o){ return new Date( o.date ) });
</script>
```

Você também pode usar isso para classificar por vários critérios, se retornar uma matriz de valores:

```
<script>
// Classificar por data e pontuar (invertido), então o nome
array.sortBy(function(o){ return [ o.date, -o.score, o.name ] };
</script>
```

Veja http://phrogz.net/JS/Array.prototype.sortBy.js para mais detalhes.